# Have IntelliJ IDEA compile and run like Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I'm trying out my school's academic license for IntelliJ. My project is in the beginning stages and has multiple Main.java in different packages.

In Eclipse, I can run a chosen Main.java and ignore errors in other packages. How can I do this in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Run/Debug configuration there's a `Before Launch` section. By default there's a `Make` action there. You can remove it and add a `Make, no error check` instead.

If you want this to be default behavior for all new Application Run/Debug configuration, you'll need to adjust the Default section instead of a concrete one.
[image: Configuration example]